# Any real number sequence can be the coefficient of Taylor series of a smooth function?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I saw such an interesting proposition:

Any given real number sequence $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} $, can construct a smooth function so that the coefficient of its Taylor series is $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} $.

Someone prompts me to construct a bulge function $\phi(x) $:

$\phi(x) :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a smooth function, $0\leqslant\phi(x) \leqslant 1$, and $$\phi \left( x\right)  =1, \;x\in \left[ -\tfrac{1}{2} ,\tfrac{1}{2} \right];\;\phi \left( x\right)  =0,\,\left\vert x\right\vert  \geqslant 1.
$$

Set $\ a_{n}\in \mathbb{R}\left( n\geqslant 0\right)  $, let $\xi_{n} =\  n\  +\  \sum^{n}_{i=0} \left\vert a_{i}\right\vert$.
Define a function$$f(x)  =\sum^{\infty }_{n=0} \frac{a_{n}}{n!} \phi \left( \xi_{n} x\right)  x^{n}$$

When $\ n\geqslant 1\ $, $\left\vert x\right\vert  \leqslant 
\xi^{-1}_{n} $,

$$\left\vert \frac{a_{n}}{n!} \phi \left( \xi_{n} x\right)  x^{n}\right\vert  \leqslant \frac{\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert  }{n!} |x|^{n}\leqslant \frac{\left\vert a_{n}\right\vert  }{n!} \frac{1}{\left( \xi_{n} \right)^{n}  } \leqslant \frac{1}{n!} $$
when $\left\vert x\right\vert >\xi^{-1}_{n}$, the upper inequality also holds.

So the series defining $f$ is uniformly convergent, $f(x)$ is continuous, and $f\left( 0\right)  =a_{0}$.

If it can be proven that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, and $f^{(n)}(0)  =a_{n}$, ${\forall}n\geqslant 1$, the conclusion is proved. But I encountered difficulties here!

I tried a proof method, but I'm not sure if there's a problem.

It only needs to prove that $\sum^{\infty }_{i=1} f^{\left( n\right)  }_{i}\left( x\right)  $ is uniformly convergent ,${\forall}n\geqslant 1$. So I tried to estimate$|\ f^{\left( n\right)  }_{i}\left( x\right)  |$:

First, from the definition of $\phi$, it can be seen that $\exists G>0, \left\vert \phi^{\left( n-k\right)  } \left( \xi_{i} x\right)  \right\vert  \leqslant G,{\forall}k\leqslant n$

We have $C^{k}_{n}\leqslant 2^{n}$ and set  $\xi_{i}>i>2$, by Newton Leibniz formula,

when i is sufficiently large, $\frac{1}{(i-k)!} < 1$,$\left\vert \xi_{i} x\right\vert  < \frac{1}{2},$ $\left\vert a_{i}x\right\vert  <\frac{\left\vert a_{i}\right\vert  }{2\xi_{i} } <2$
$$|\ f^{\left( n\right)  }_{i}\left( x\right)  |=\left\vert \sum^{n}_{k=0} C^{k}_{n}\frac{a_{i}}{i!} \phi^{\left( n-k\right)  } \left( \xi_{i} x\right)  \left( \xi_{i} \right)^{n-k}  x^{i-k}\frac{i!}{(i-k)!} \right\vert  $$
$$=\left\vert \sum^{n}_{k=0} C^{k}_{n}\frac{a_{i}}{(i-k)!} \phi^{\left( n-k\right)  } \left( \xi_{i} x\right)^{}  \left( \xi_{i} x\right)^{n-k}  x^{i-n}\right\vert  
$$
$$\leqslant \left\vert \sum^{n}_{k=0} a_{i}x\cdot 2^{n}\phi^{\left( n-k\right)  } \left( \xi_{i} x\right) \left( \frac{1}{\xi_{i} } \right)^{i-n-1}   \right\vert  
$$
$$\leqslant \left\vert \sum^{n}_{k=0}  2^{n+1}\phi^{\left( n-k\right)  } \left( \xi_{i} x\right) \left( \frac{1}{\xi_{i} } \right)^{i-n-1}   \right\vert  
$$
$$\leqslant \left\vert \sum^{n}_{k=0}  2^{n+1}G \cdot\left( \frac{1}{2 } \right)^{i-n-1}   \right\vert  
$$
$$=n\cdot 2^{2n+2}G\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{i}  $$it indicates that $\sum^{\infty }_{i=1} f^{\left( n\right)  }_{i}\left( x\right)  $ is uniformly convergent.

May I ask if my proof is correct? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This fact is a special case of Borel's Lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma

Comment: Great theorem! But I haven't learned enough so far to understand the proof of this theorem

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This proposition is to find a smooth function so that its n-th derivative at 0 is $a_{n}$.  $\phi $ is a cut- off function, and I hope to control $a_{n}$by selecting $\xi_{n}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe there's something wrong with my expression, the coefficients can be solved by making a substitution$b_{n}=n!an$, the propositional conclusion should be that $f$ is not required to be defined by a power series, it just needs f to be infinitely differentiable, which means that it can be expanded to a Taylor series at 0, and after making the substitution, the coefficients of this Taylor series are exactly $a_{n}$ according to the definition of $f$.

Comment: Nevermind - I now see that you are just saying that any Taylor series is possible, not that the series converges to $f$ anywhere but at $0$.